# Sharing pygame/python withought using any compiler

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried many times to use a compiler like `cx_freeze` and other programs, but for some reason nothing seems to be working. I made a little game which I want to send to a friend, but he needs python installed.

Can't I just put `python.exe` and pygame into the folder that I will send my friend and won't python be installed then, and all he needs to do is run the program `.py` and it will work? Sorry if I'm not being clear.. I'm just trying to find a simple way to compile my code to let users not waste time on downloading pygame and python.

Comment: I am not using C or C ++ so ???

Comment: Cython can generate C files from Python code, which can then be compiled into an executable with a program like `gcc`.

Comment: If the source doesn't have to be protected, you could try py2exe or pyinstaller.

Comment: py2exe doesnt work for me for reasons, pyinstaller I did try, yet that also didn't work. Im just wondering if I can just put pygame and python inside a folder with the game, so when a user downloades that folder all he has to do is open the .py game and python.exe would run it

Comment: Take a look at http://www.pygame.org/project-pyg.exe-2830-.html

Comment: Ok i'll try it out, thanks......................................................................................                                 Ok I tried it out, and the instructions arn't quite clear on what to do, I tried following some of it, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you tried cx_freeze and it didn't work, you tried py2exe and it didn't work, you tried pyinstaller and it didn't work, and now you've tried pyg.exe and it didn't work... maybe you could tell us what about them didn't work? It's not entirely unexpected that these processes don't work perfectly the first time you try them out.

Comment: Ok so cx_freeze didn't work because the first time it got corrupted, second time it just could not find the files I made yet they were in the correct directory. When they did work there was a bug with my version of windows. I tried pyinstaller, but it doesnt work for python 3.2, so I updgraded to 3.4. There were problems with the modules I was using there. Pyg.exe seems like an awesome idea, Theres just not clear instructions on it, so im kind of confused on that. I did not try them out one time and give up.. I tried working wtih them with different python version but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) allows you to package python applications for Windows. Right now it supports everything from 2.4 - 3.1 of python. You do however need to be able to redistribute MSVCR90.dll.

There are a range of distribution tools and you can find a list [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities).

Since you've had difficultly with several tools now updating your question with error codes and speific problems will yeild better responses.

Comment: I started writing this before reading the comments posted to the answer.  Yes, please provide more information so we're better able to help.

Comment: Well I have python 3.4 so I cant use py2exe. cx_freeze I have asked many questions on and looked online but it just doesn't work.  I would appreciate if yo could explain how to use pyg.exe, I have no idea how t use that. Pyinstaller, I'll try to use it again. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Ok, I linked to a list of packaging tools you can try.

As for not knowing, I've included a link to a tutorial. If you could try following that and getting to an error people will be able to answer your questions. Without more information it is really difficult to help other than to link you to a list of tools.

Comment: The link above with the distribution tools mostly deal wit pyhon 2.X so can't use that, now sure where the tutorial link is?

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge, just putting a bunch of your stuff in one folder and sending doesn't work. It would be easier to make a .exe

That way your stuff will be protected, and users can easily start it. Otherwise idk. Try using pyinstaller again. It should work if you have a python.x

CX_Freeze is known for having many bugs and problems, Pyg.exe is new to me also. Your best bet is just keep trying until you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Putting python.exe and your script together in a folder will not work for distribution. You require all Python dependencies - at best your would need to include all of your Python folder, and it still might not work. The best method would be compilation or packaging with programs such as py2exe, cx_freeze, Cython, pyg.exe, etc.